# Proof of relation for open superset

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Currently reading a textbook on measure theory. To complete a proof the author uses (without proof) the relation:
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n \setminus E_n)$$

where $E_n\subset A_n$ and $A_n$ is **open** for every $n$. How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct element-chasing:

If $x \in \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \setminus \cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, then $x \in \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and $x \notin \cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. So there is $N$ such that $x \in A_N$ and then of course $x \notin E_N$. Thus $x \in A_N \setminus E_N \subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty \left( A_n \setminus E_n \right)$.